# Ethics of publishing covariate matrix

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, covariance-matrix, reproducible-research, open-source, ethics

I am planning to submit a paper with a Structural Equation Model applied into a dataset built with measurements from schizophrenic patients. In the spirit of promoting an open research culture I've been considering giving the readers access to the covariance table, so the paper could be further used as didactic tool and also allow immediate access to the "underpinnings" of the work.

Are there ethical issues that I should take into consideration? On my understanding there is no way of reverse-engineer that information. Are there any other issues that I may consider before attempting this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is no way to reverse engineer the information. But, the ethics of data remain as is, and one needs to respect them before sharing information which has been mined from that data.

So, you need to take written permission from the lab which have done the experiments. If it is your lab, then include the permissions certificate you have obtained for the experiments.

Comment: How is publishing the covariance tabel much different from publishing something like results and standard errors? Why should that require any additional permission? Isn't this already assumed to be included in any granted permissions that are neccesary for writing a scientific publication about the experiments/measurements?